# What is this behind the drywall?

Tags: drywall

Was drilling to install a pretty heavy mirror. All other holes were okay, but encountered
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSuGb.jpg)

Feels like plastic. Is immediately behind the drywall - the drywall is barely 0.1 inch here. This wall is facing the exterior of the house.

Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: 6 mil poly.  vapor barrier - installed on the warm side of insulation (in primary heating climates) behind drywall on exterior walls.

Comment: If it is directly under the paint and barely .1 on an inch in, it may be a tape joint of some sort or joint compound. The drywall is typically much thicker.

Comment: Thanks. Presumably not something to be drilled into?